# Displaying all fields of Foreign Key Model

Tags: django, database, django-models

What I want is to retrieve all the fields belonging to a Model of a foreign key.

My models for example:

```
class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='N/A')
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)

class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,null=False)
    sofa = models.ForeignKey(SofaProduct, blank=True, null=True)
    toaster = models.ForeignKey(ToasterProduct, blank=True, null=True)
```

These are just examples, there can be any number of ProductType models each with any number of fields.

In my template I can display all the fields of the BaseProduct by using the BaseProduct ID. What I want is to display all the fields of the FK.

For example if type = sofa in BaseProduct, I need to retrieve and display all sofa fields as well as BaseProduct fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(disclaimer: I have a tendency to give really long answers. You'll have to forgive me for that)

First rule of schema design - It should reflect your real world [business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) (not the [actual business action](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194446/how-much-business-logic-should-the-database-implement) mind you, just the implications of the relationships). For example, if I have a class `Person` I can create a class `Pet` with a foreginKey to `Person` which translates to - every person can have multiple pets.

If we apply that logic to your schema we see that `ProductType` is a class that has a foreignKey to both Sofas and Toasters, which means each Toaster can have multiple Sofas and vice versa. Last time I checked, I never heard of a Sofa that had a Toaster.

In other words - you need to think what you're actually trying to achieve here. I'm guessing `BaseProduct` is a basic class that has common fields, and Sofa and Toaster are different types of products. Since they are different, they have their own special fields, and shouldn't be related, so it makes sense to have them as separate models. So why do you even need `ProductType`? To define the name `Toaster`? You're already defining an entire model! Why do you need to keep its name on a different table (and not, say, some custom method that always returns `"I am a toaster, hear me roar"`)?

My best guess is that you want to be able to define new types of products on the go. However, if you intend to keep them separated on the model level, then you'll have to create a model for each new product. And if you want to be able to simple define a new model with `ProductType`, then you either need to have one Product class to manage them all, or you want  a complicated dynamic system that can create new models on the fly.

Let's break those options down:

1. Create a generic product and a type class, like you did there:

   ```
   class ProductType(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,null=False)

   class Product(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
       variant = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='N/A')
       type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)
   ```

   Now each product can only be of one type, and you can always create new types on the go. This of course means all Product objects will share the same fields, and is very limiting. You won't have the same flexibility for each type like you would before (no sofa-only fields), but on the other hand it will be easier to create dynamic types of objects - you just define a new `ProductType` and bam you have a whole new group of products.
2. Create a basic [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) Product model, and define a new sub-model for each new type of product. You'll have a lot more flexibility for each one, but defining new types will always require defining a new model and setting up a table for it. With this scheme you don't need the `ProductType` object at all because the different models define the different types (there's no need for duplicity).

   You can create some kind of admin page for the process, but it's not going
   to be very easy to setup, and you might find yourself eventually with too many tables
   (which can be especially problematic if you need to sometimes query
   on all products - you'll have to join a lot of different tables,
   which is not very efficient).
3. Use a [non-relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) with some [dynamic-models know how](http://dynamic-models.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [disco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UkSPUDpe0U8#t=11s)*

*ok, it's actually more complicated than that, but the explanation on how to combine them is way too long, even for my answer. If it seems over your head, forget about it. If you have some idea about how non-relation databases work, you can probably figure it out yourself

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear.

I think you want Django modal forms to display all fields of an modal.

```
def ListForm(Forms.form):
    model = MyModel
    fields='__all__'          #Sets display all
    fk_name ="Model_to_use"   #Is needed when your model has more then one fk
```

[Django model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_set` for accessing related objects. For example, if you have two models like these:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    somedata = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,null=False)
    referral = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,null=False)
```

you can access the name field of AnotherModel with

```
>>> m = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
>>> m.AnotherModel_set.all()[0].name
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

On a side note, you should probably rethink your models structure, as [yuvi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26775474/2926113).